# Why am I having problems installing Adobe Air on Linux Mint 14 and what is the solution?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, gnome-keyring

I am attempting to install Adobe Air 2.6 on Linux Mint 14 in order to install an application that is dependent upon it.

I was instructed to install the getlibs-all package which I did and was able to get slightly further in the installation process.  However, I am now stuck scratching my head over the following error message:

```
Adobe AIR could not be installed.  
Install either Gnome Keyring or KDE KWallet before installing Adobe AIR.
```

I already installed gnome-keyring through the Synaptic Package Manager, so I'm not sure why the installer is complaining.  I have also installed python-keyring, kwalletmanager, and kwalletcli with no difference in outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If everything works, all should be installed. If you run into problems with adobe Air about missing gnome-keyring or KDE Wallet, run the commands below to fix it.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0 /usr/lib/libgnome-keyring.so.0.2.0
```

Now, try again.

---

Credits: http://ubuntumisr.blogspot.com.br/2013/02/install-adobe-air-in-ubuntu-1204.html